# Error Compling a C program?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

After hours and hours of working on a program, and eliminating all the syntax errors, I came across this error which I have no idea what is or why it there. This is the error:

```
/tmp/ccKnig3z.o: In function `main':
line_formula_convert.c:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `intcp_from_pt_slope'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's the whole program, if it is of any help for you.
http://pastebin.com/9CNsaaF0
I am using Fedora 19, and gcc -Wall in compiling my program. Any help explaining this error is appreciated, and I am sorry if this is an elementary question.

Comment: has intcp_from_pt_slope been defined ?

Comment: @user1281385 yes, and also it has a protype in the begging.

Comment: Do you have all of your code in just one file, or is it spread across different files? If so, what are the commands used to compile and link?

Comment: Code is all in one file.

Comment: @Andy then where intcp_from_pt_slope defined?

Comment: New to C programming ? From where did you copy this code ?
Before using any library make sure you understand how to use its functions, how to link it. `intcp_from_pt_slope` is not any standard built-in function. All answers here will be just a guess.

Comment: "Where did you copy this code?" What do you mean @P0W???? All the functions are defined later on in the program, and all functions have prototypes in the begging of the file. And I didn't copy it from anywhere. I wrote this code.The only reason I posted main,was because people requested it.

Comment: Also, why so many dislikes?????

Comment: It's really just guessing, but can you see any differences between the declaration (line with `;` at the end) and the definition (where there is the `{`/`}` block) of the function whose call causes the undefined reference error versus another function that seems to work, say `get_pt_slope`?

Comment: Misspelling: function definition uses `incp_from_pt_slope` which misses the `t` of `intc...`

Comment: @Andy see the typo in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright now we are talking, after you've posted the link for your code.

```
void incp_from_pt_slope(double x1, double y1, double m, double *b) ;
       |
void intcp_from_pt_slope(double x1, double y1, double m, double *b);
```

Did you see difference ? `incp_from_pt_slope` is not same as `incp_from_pt_slope`, and that's why linker complains that undefined reference error.

Comment: Awesome.Thanks a lot. The funny thing is I checked for spelling twice,and I didn't detect it. I guess because it's 1:58 am right now, and I have working on this program for about 4 hours. But I should have triple checked.

Comment: @Andy The compiler would have helped you if you had used the option `-Wmissing-prototypes`.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks @blackbird But doesn't `-Wall` do the trick?

Comment: @Andy obviously not :) have a look at the documentation http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `#include` for the declaration
2. Use `-l` option to link to the library
3. Read the manual page for the compiler

Comment: I am not using the math library, and I tried this before asking and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a call in your code to a function called `intcp_from_pt_slope` which is not defined anywhere. The error occurs from the linker. Each module of your program is compiled separately and you use prototypes to declare functions that may exist in separate compilation units (.c files). The linker then takes all the object files and resolves all the functions so that every function is pointing to something that has been given an implementation. If it cannot find an implementation for a function, you get the error you have reported. This may be because you missed an object from the linker command line, or you just typed the name incorrectly.

It is probably a typo and you need a space between the int and cp_from_pt_slope.

Comment: It's not int cp_from_pt_slope. THE Name is intcp_from_pt_slope in which intcp stands for intercept